# EXC_BAD_ACCESS at UIApplicationMain - how to interpret this backtrace?

Tags: ios, debugging, crash, exc-bad-access

```
#0  0x0149609b in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x06a75960 in ?? ()
#2  0x0108df9a in _performRunLoopAction ()
#3  0x0131189b in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#4  0x012a66e7 in __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
#5  0x0126f1d7 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#6  0x0126e840 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#7  0x0126e761 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#8  0x01c871c4 in GSEventRunModal ()
#9  0x01c87289 in GSEventRun ()
#10 0x00393c93 in UIApplicationMain ()
#11 0x00001f68 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff028) at /Users/Stu/Documents...
```

I'm a little confused by the `?? ()` near the top. On seeing that this error appeared at the line `int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);` I assumed a memory access problem to do with the autorelease pool, but I haven't found any so far.

The error happens when I call for a CoreData object with a certain property to be deleted. This process takes an NSDate object, finds the core data object with that date as its 'timestamp', and deletes that object.

I have NSZombie enabled along with NSDebug and MallocStackLogging, however no info is shown in the log (other than the backtrace when I request it of course). Stepping through the code doesn't help narrow down the problem either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved.

As I originally speculated, it was indeed to do with the autorelease pool (always trust your instinct...). For some bizarre reason - probably after not sleeping for 36 hours - I had autoreleased an object that had no business being autoreleased. It was just a simple custom getter-style method that returns a text object that is currently selected.

Not sure why an NSZombie wasn't created for it though...

Comment: i'm betting you only thought you had NSZombie=YES set while running

Comment: Nope, NSZombieEnabled is definitely set to YES. I have a separate scheme set up for debugging, in which I keep all the necessary variables enabled. Also, while stepping through the code earlier, I noticed other objects turning into zombies as they were released.

Answer (score 2):

objc_msgSend() causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS usually means that a function is not implemented in the target object. We can also see that an Observer callback is being made. I would venture to guess that you somewhere called -addObserver:selector:name:object: with the wrong selector.
(this is usually printed just before the stack trace).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have actually now found the solution, and it was indeed to do with memory management (facepalm). I will post an explanation in a new answer. It's only a guess, but I suppose the observer callback could be to do with the UIMenuController item that was clicked to initiate the action? Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: +1 for giving me a little insight into the stack trace by the way, which was what the question was asking for.